# problem with insertion in primary key when changing mysql version

Tags: mysql

We are migrating an application from one server to another. The MySql version of the old server is 5.6.51, the new one is 5.7.33

We have a problem with the application inserts in the tables and it has to do with the primary key.
The inserts in the tables that are made using Perl.

In this way they do not work on the new server, however on the old one if:

```
INSERT INTO Clients VALUES ('', ...);
```

In this way if they work:

```
INSERT INTO Clients VALUES (null, ...);
```

It is a configuration problem or it is due to a change in the MySql version?

Comment: did you check the migration path on the homepage?

Comment: No, this is not configuration problem, this is version difference.

Comment: I would not expect `INSERT INTO Clients VALUES ('', ...);` to work. That's just plain wrong. Sounds like they fixed a bug.

Comment: I suggest you search the [release notes for the 5.7 series](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/) and find the release where they fixed that bug.